# forzar redireccionamiento si se cumple la regla .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

En mi web, manejo lenguajes de este modo

dominio.com/es/
dominio.com/br/
dominio.com/en/
etc...

Quiero saber la forma con "htaccess" de redireccionar forsozamente la url, si el usuario entra asi 
**dominio.com/**

forzarlo a que vaya hacia:
**dominio.com/es/**

Comment: Iba a comentar lo del index.html, pero aún no tengo los puntos para comentar :) El refresh require otra comunicación con el cliente, ida y vuelta, entonces es mucho más lento y ineficaz que hacerlo todo en el servidor con .htaccess.

Answer (score 3):

Si la idea es simplemente redireccionar el dominio raíz, entonces esa sección htaccess debería quedar así:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ es [L]
```

Comment: No me funciona  
será por que uso subdominio?

PD: Como pongo codigo y saltos de linea en este comentario?

Comment: No tiene nada que ver el uso de un subdominio, está instalado el módulo de rewrite?

Comment: Claro que si amigo. Ya tengo URLs amigables, solo me falta hacer esta redireccion.
Nose como dejar codigo en este comentario, para poner lo que tengo actualmente.

Comment: Agrégalo a la pregunta (editándola)

Answer (score 0):

Por qué usar un `.htacces` para direccionar una sola dirección? Bastaría con poner un `index.html` (o la extensión que corresponda) en la raíz  (`dominio.com/index.html`) con un refresh que haga el redirect.

Hacerlo con `.htacces` es un desperdicio, porque ese archivo sería parseado para cada consulta al sitio (y no es cacheado).

Comment: Quiero redireccionar a dominio.com/es/
Ya que "es" es un parametro, y es indispensable, redireccionar a este parametro, no me vale ni poner "index.php" ni "index.html"... En este caso, mejor lo dejo tal cual.

Comment: No entiendo. Lo que quieres es direccionar la (sola) url "http://dominio.com/" a "http://dominio.com/es/" , no? Si es asi, te estoy proponiendo poner un index.html en tu document root, con lo cual cuando alguien acceda a "http://dominio.com/" apache le devolverá ese index.html, el cual tendra una redireccion (via refresh) a "http://dominio.com/es/" Donde está el problema?

Comment: Aunque creo que no hay ningún problema en esta solución, y puede haber un retraso (descartable) por hacer una solicitud http, al parecer no es tan recomendable para el SEO: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

Comment: lo que pasa que `dominio.com/es/` == `index.php?lang=es`    asi que no puedo poner un index.html o index.php o index.htm    saludos

Comment: Ah, pero entonces ya tienes un .htaccess con rewrite andando, deberias haberlo posteado

Answer (score 0):

para que funcione con cualquier dominio, solo pondría una regla que sea "En el caso de que no empiece con ningun lenguaje, redirige a /es/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?!es|en|br)(.*) /es/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^(es|en|br/)(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

la segunda regla está comentada, es justamente el caso contrario y la dejo por si acaso.

Sería bueno también pasar en las opciones, la opción `QSA` que indica que si viene un `query string`, este sea anexado a la URL. Pero esto ya depende de tu aplicación

PD: probado con [Htaccess Tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)